# NoSQL + AngularJS: treeview pattern with flat hierarchy?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, nosql

in my table I've **5000 items** on the same hierarchy level, sortable by it's `position`:

```
ID  | Position
--------------
1   | 2  
2   | 3
3   | 1
...
```

I'd like to create a treeview **without changing the schema**.

Is there a **common pattern or a best practise** to achieve a treeview with a table structured like the following?

```
ID  | Position
--------------
7   | 2  
8   | 2.1
9   | 2.2
17  | 2.2.9
...
```

I'm trying another approach than working with `parent_id`, nested sets or nested json objects to display the tree, but I'm not sure if it's a good way.

The tree should be managed with AngularJS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, keeping nested  JSON Object as nested fromt in document is better that flat system. Because to display tree you must have to manupulate the JSON object as nested way.